# Exception Router using Annotation

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to convert my code into java annotation but i am stuck with

```
<int:exception-type-router input-channel="failed-email-fetch"  default-output-channel="errorChannel">
        <int:mapping exception-type="com.XXXXXX.RateException" channel="customError" />
</int:exception-type-router>
```

if i used `@Router` i did not know what to return and this what i used but did not work

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "failedEmailFetch")
public ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter handleError(MessageHandlingException messageHandlingException) {
    ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter errorMessageExceptionTypeRouter = new ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter();
    errorMessageExceptionTypeRouter.setChannelMapping("com.XXXXXX.exception.MessageException","customError");
    errorMessageExceptionTypeRouter.setDefaultOutputChannelName("errorChannel");
    return errorMessageExceptionTypeRouter;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need `@Bean` when the `@ServiceActivator` annotation is on a `MessageHandler`.

`@ServiceActivator` alone is for POJO messaging.

See [Annotations on Beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans).

Consuming endpoints have 2 beans, the handler and a consumer; the `@ServiceActivator` defines the consumer. The `@Bean` is the hander.

Comment: thanks gary, i missed that  i will test it and check

Comment: Worked perfectly , but i had to use setChannelMappings instead of setChannelMapping

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the below not sure if it is the best way

```
   @Router(inputChannel = "failedEmailFetch",defaultOutputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public String handleError(Message<AggregateMessageDeliveryException> message) {
        log.info("{}",message.getPayload().getCause().getCause());
        if( message.getPayload().getRootCause() instanceof MessageException)
            return "customError";
        else
            return "errorChannel";
    }
```